# Code editor (maybe Scite?) to write Java under Windows XP

Tags: java, text-editor, ide, windows-xp

I am looking for an edition of [SCiTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciTE) for Microsoft Windows XP along with its supporting JAVA SDK. I searched in Google with different terms but I didn't get any proper results or download link for it.

Please some one point me to the exact download site for SCiTE and JAVA JDK, both of which should work in Microsoft Windows XP operating system.

If possible please write the steps to install it in my computer — I heard about environment variable settings but I don't know how that works.

Comment: Why Scite should support JDK?? Install any code editor. E.g. SynWrite or PSPad. Then use JDK in this editor.

Comment: Someone need to learn JAVA with SCITE only. That's the reason I'm looking for SCITE supported JDK.

Comment: But other eds can support Java too: in Synwrite create "user-tool" with link to Javac.exe and u can compile Java app from inside editor.

Comment: Yes, it's for WinXP.

Comment: @RProgram Could you make this into an answer?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer, his comment doesn't satisfied my needs, so its better to leave it as comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Hemang I disagree. The question is not just for you but for everyone having this problem. While it may not be sufficient for your specific case it seems to answer the overall concept. As comments go away after a while (iirc) answers stay and can be voted on etc. If it doesn't fit you need, just don't accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why Scite should support JDK?? Install other editor. E.g. **SynWrite** or **CudaText**. Then use JDK in this editor.

Editors can support Java too: in SynWrite create "user-tool" with link to Javac.exe and you can compile Java app from inside editor, running this tool.

Preset in SynWrite exists:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/) is a lightweight cross-platform GUI based text editor that uses Scintilla. It supports java syntax, and it can be configured to compile and build java projects. [Here](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html) you can find the detailed manual with instructions on how to install and configure it.

[Download link for Geany](http://www.geany.org/Download/Releases)
[Download link for JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/index.html)